# Is there a way to open a dataset when I click on a section in pie chart?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create a pie chart and when I click on a section I should get a dataframe displayed.
For example I might create the following pie chart:

```
# Create data for the graph.
x <- c(21, 62, 10, 53)
labels <- c("London", "New York", "Singapore", "Mumbai")

# Give the chart file a name.
png(file = "city.png")

# Plot the chart.
pie(x,labels)
```

[image]

Now lets say **when I click on a slice such as 'london' I get the IRIS datset.**

Solution i used:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

df <- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RT5AkCef4cehEaGelK0avbXAtck1f-Ap/view   #READ THIS DATA HERE
setDT(df)
dtnum <- df[ , .N, by="V3"]
dtnum2 <- df[ , .N, by="V2"]
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  plotlyOutput("myPlot"),
  plotlyOutput("myPlot2"),
  DTOutput("mydt")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    print(d)
    if (is.null(d)) {
      df
    } else {
      output$mydt <- renderDT({
        df[V3 == d$customdata]
      })
    }
  })
  output$myPlot2 <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(dtnum2, labels = ~V2, values = ~N, type = 'pie', customdata = ~V2)
  }) 
  
  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(dtnum, labels = ~V3, values = ~N, type = 'pie', customdata = ~V3)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `pie()` will get you a picture. Therefore we need something else to build the piechart. Maybe "highcharter" is the one you seek. There are a few topics on that. If you want to connect it to a table, I think you will need to use shiny.

good luck. I am eager to see a result. sound like a good idea!

Comment: Check out my solution in my edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example using `shiny`, `plotly` and `DT`.

To understand what's going on please check the plotly book on [linking views with shiny](https://plotly-r.com/linking-views-with-shiny.html) and [supplying custom data](https://plotly-r.com/supplying-custom-data.html).

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(datasets)
library(shiny)

irisDT <- copy(iris)
setDT(irisDT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("myPlot"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("myTable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly({
    irisCountDT <- irisDT[,.N, by="Species"]
    fig <- plot_ly(irisCountDT, labels = ~Species, values = ~N, type = 'pie', source = "myPlotSource", customdata = ~Species)
  })
  
  myPlotEventData <- reactive({
    event_data(
      event = "plotly_click",
      source = "myPlotSource")
    })
  
  output$myTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(irisDT[Species %in% myPlotEventData()$customdata[[1]]])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Also check plotly's [capabilities regarding crosstalk](https://plotly-r.com/client-side-linking.html) in this context.

Comment: Mindblowing! Let me spend some time to get my head around it. I thought this wouldnt be possible and i should give up

Comment: What does source = "myPlotSource" do? I am having a little trouble understanding this one

Comment: It links the plot and the event_data reactive. This is important when having multiple plots to receive events from, so you can define what goes where.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was finally able to do it on my data too. https://i.imgur.com/LFOfLF9.png

Comment: I have posted my solution based on your code in my edit. Also i added multiple pie charts now. Would it be possible to show data from multiple pie charts into the same table?

Comment: I my eyes that should go into a separate question tagged [shiny] - please use the output of `dput(df)` instead of google drive to share your data.

Comment: I have posted a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70113381/create-a-data-table-when-click-on-section-of-different-pie-charts

Comment: I share your view ujjwal, ismirsehregal turns the impossible into the possible!

Comment: Thanks @Curious Jorge-user9788072! Just FYI all those upvotes were removed again (from my internal score). SO automatically detects and reverses serial voting.

Comment: Wow!! That's too bad, your posts are always tops and I've been upvoting those posts more related to what I'm working on. Nothing random. This OP is a perfect example where you access a dataset by clicking on a chart, it'll be very useful for my projects. Oh well, live and learn.

Comment: Is anyone having trouble achieving this with a plotly histogram? Where you each bar is an interval